# Exclude Block on Drupal

Tags: drupal

I need to stop a certain block from appearing on a certain page on a Drupal site.  I went to admin->site building->blocks and set the block I wanted not to appear on the page I don't want it on.  However, this change is only effecting logged in users, anonymous users still see the block.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Turns out it the block had two different names depending on whether you were logged in as an admin or as a regular user.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like it might be a cache issue: anonymous users get pre-rendered pages from the cache, so your change wouldn't affect them until the cache is cleared.

Try running http://www.yoursite.com/devel/cache/clear if you have `devel` installed, or resetting the cache at http://www.yoursite.com/admin/settings/performance if you're not using `devel`.